# Where can I get the list of Repository for Yum in Ubuntu?

Tags: repository, installation, yum

I have a vanilla machine (Ubuntu) and I just did **apt-get install yum**

However, the yum.cof has empty repos list.  So, where can I get the most updated list of repository?

Comment: Please, for the love of Cthulhu, use only *one* package manager! But if you insist, what do you mean by "repositories for yum"? There's Fedora's repositories, if those work.

Comment: what i mean is, the yum.conf  has empty list. 

so, will the repo for fedora works on ubuntu? http://www.xades.com/proj/fedora_repos.html  <--is it hte one?

Comment: Before I answer, do you understand that this can and probably will completely obliterate your Ubuntu install? Why are you in need of `yum`? If you need `yum`, get Fedora. Ubuntu uses `apt`, and it's dangerous to have multiple package managers.

Comment: `apt` and `yum` might have different versions of packages, and when they install, they can overwrite files already in place, as the two managers do not communicate with each other. When you upgrade a crucial package, like `glibc`, and you don't upgrade packages which depend on it, your system will be dead.

Comment: ok.. so, instead of yum, i should use apt-get, right?

Comment: Definitely. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Blender you mentioned that you'd be willing to answer the question after risks have been clearified. I'd really much appreciate it :)

Comment: @KarlRichter: It just isn't going to work. Ubuntu's made out of components packaged as Debian packages. Unless you plan on building your own Ubuntu-compatible RPM packages, there's no reason to use yum.

Comment: @Blender I'm using an RPM-based distro with APT as the higher level package manager -- http://en.altlinux.org . What I could be interested is a yum module for APT, which would fetch packages from 3rd-party yum repos, and rely on the APT machinery to satisfy their deps with our "native" RPMs from our distro whenever I want to install a 3rd-party package. From the yum repo's URL, I can't figure out where to download the RPMs (the webserver hides them), so I'd like yum to fetch the packages from the locations it is aware about.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the repolist option to the `yum` command. This option will show you a list of configured repositories under RHEL / Fedora / SL / CentOS Linux.

The default is to list all enabled repositories. Pass `-v` (verbose mode) as an option to the `yum` command to list more information.

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned here](https://serverfault.com/q/735509/783)::

- Ubuntu natively uses deb packages, not rpm. yum is for the redhat rpm variant.
- yum is the package management tool on RHEL-derived distributions and Fedora, Ubuntu uses apt instead.

So using `apt` (see [apt-get HowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)) remains the recommended package management.